# Java Threads and Synchronize

Tags: java

I'm working on a lab assignment and I'm a bit stuck on how to implement a specific class. My task is to create a program that simulates "Trolls" crossing a bridge. The Trolls are represented by threads. This is part of the Troll class I've written:

```
public class Troll implements Runnable {
// instance variables

// constructor

    public void run() {
        System.out.println( name + " has arrived at the bridge.");
        System.out.println( name + " is starting to cross.");

        // simulate crossing time
        for( int i = 1; i <= crossingTime; ++i ) {
            try{
                Thread.sleep( 1000 ); 
            }
            catch( InterruptedException e ) {}
            System.out.println( "\t" + name + " " + i + " seconds." );
        }
        System.out.println( name + " leaves at " + destination + "." );
    }
}
```

Now the part I'm stuck on is my "Bridge" class. The Bridge class is suppose to ensure only 1 Troll crosses the bridge at a time. The bridge class must only have these 2 methods with the same method signature:

```
//request permission to enter bridge
public void enterBridge() {}
//notify bridge that Troll is leaving
public void leaveBridge() {}
```

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to make use of these methods. The hint I got from the instructions is to use synchronize. I believe this means to use a synchronized block in `enterBridge`, but I don't see how this would work. The code that simulates the actual crossing is in the Troll's run method (this is required by the lab). So to begin crossing, you have to exit the synchronized block. This would release the "lock" and then other trolls will begin crossing before the previous Troll has finished, which is not wanted.

I don't really see the need of the Bridge methods in the first place, since I can just put the code in my Troll's run method in a synchronized block:

```
public void run() {
    System.out.println( name + " has arrived at the bridge.");
    synchronized( bridge ) {
        //Code from before
   }
}
```

This ensures only one Trolls is crossing at a time without needing to call the Bridge class methods. So can someone tell me what the lab is getting at with the Bridge class? I feel like I'm overlooking something obvious or maybe I'm misunderstanding how synchronize works.

Comment: **Hint**: You should have a `synchronized` block which contains both 
`public void enterBridge()` & `public void leaveBridge()` as you only want one thread access both of these methods simultaneously.

Comment: I think your understanding of `synchronized` is fine, and you need some other methods.  Look up `wait` and `notify` in the [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class; or perhaps some classes in `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: I was going to use wait in enterBridge and notify in leaveBridge, however I looked at the next part of my assignment and these were the things I was suppose to add next. So I believe that I am suppose to do it without wait/notify first.

Comment: I think your solution is correct (`synchronized` block inside `run()` method, enclosing calls to enter and leave bridge). However, more clarity on how you set things up is needed. How do you initialize the `Troll` threads so that they are given the same `Bridge` instance to cross? Is it possible for your TA to provide his own bridge implementation, or to invoke your code from some larger program? Do you have total control over *all* threads in that VM? Because if not, I can think of some tricks the instructor could pull to break your solution.

Comment: @erickson The Troll class contains an instance variable that holds   `Bridge`. I have control over the threads. The program runs through a main method in `Troll` that creates all the threads.

Comment: If there will be many instances of your "Troll," it doesn't really make sense for the Main class to be there.

Comment: @user2345351 This seems like a rather weird assignment, then.  Maybe they want you to have `enterBridge` and `leaveBridge` access a volatile variable, such as a `boolean` that tells whether there's a troll on the bridge, and have `enterBridge` spin until the bridge is empty.  I could imagine `synchronized` being used when accessing the variable.

Comment: @RhinoFeeder The main class is just for testing. I thought it was weird to have it there as well but I'm just following the assignment instructions. I'm sure my instructor will have his own separate class used to test my classes.

Comment: @ajb Yes the assignment is quite confusing for me. I thought using a sync block in the run method was the correct solution, however I got to the next part and I was required to implement wait/notify and was only allowed to modify the Bridge class. The sync block would prevent that from working. I think your suggestion may be correct though. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve your problem using a semaphore. Semaphores can be found in java.util.concurrent. Semaphore are a slightly overkill solution in the case where a single Troll is crossing the bridge at a time, but will become handy when several Trolls will be able to run through the bridge at the same time.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation on [Guarded Blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html)

Comment: Don't worry, Jim. I purposely left out a lot of other lab requirements to avoid this sort of thing. This solution wouldn't work for me even if I was tempted to use it.

Comment: The GuardedBlocks link was helpful. Thank you.